# How to encrypt a file with newline feed

Tags: java, security, encryption

I am encrypting a file, but the encrypted file comes with a continuous string.
I want output the same way as my input file. see for example

```
input file:
===========
Language,English

System Name,TSLGN0

Number of board SPC,12
.
.
Output Encrypted file:
========================
ADCDE12345456

ABCDDDDDDDEDEDAAAADDDD12333

ABCDE123456789

.
.
```

What I am getting:

```
760bad166e25ea1e2f6a741363816a15703f2e20524503eee544f69909dd69af760bad166e25ea1e2f
```

Code below:

```
BufferedWriter bwr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Crypto_Out.txt")));

mbr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Crypto_In.txt"));
while ((line = mbr.readLine()) != null) 
{
    enSecretText=encrypt(line);
    bwr.write(enSecretText.toString());
}

bwr.flush();
bwr.close();
```

Please suggest

Comment: When you encrypt each line individually and want the original newlines, why don't you put a newline after each encrypted line?

Comment: Please add the code for your `encrypt()` method if you want to get any useful answers.

Comment: Maybe add the linebreaks manually after encypting the line? `bwr.write(enSecretText.toString() + "\n");` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a newline at the end of every iteration.

```
while ((line = mbr.readLine()) != null) 
{
    enSecretText=encrypt(line);
    bwr.write(enSecretText.toString());
    bwr.newLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works                                                                                      Infact, I need to add twice                                                                              bwr.newLine(); bwr.newLine();

Answer (score 1):

Encryption treats files as a stream of bytes.  It is not interested in the meaning assigned to those bytes, just how to encrypt them.  Your encrypted ciphertext will be a continuous stream of bytes.  It is up to you how to handle that ciphertext.

If you want the ciphertext as letters, then encode it as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).  If you want to add newlines to your Base64 then you can do so, but your **must** remove the newlines before removing the Base64 to get back to the original ciphertext bytes.

Decrypting the ciphertext bytes will get back to your original text.

Comment: Note: Some Base64 implementations will automatically remove newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `add bwr.newLine();` after `bwr.write`.